# full desktop backup using adb not working with yu yureka

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, micromax-yu-yureka

I am using a desktop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed to do a full desktop backup of my Yu yureka phone.

I used the command

```
sudo adb backup --all
```

then it shows

```
Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.
```

But nothing is ever shown on the phone. The phone is running on Cyanogenmod OS 11.(I want to do a full backup before updating it to CM12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means, the device, haven't any **PIN** password.

just do this :

> `Goto Settings > LockScreen > Screen Lock`

and set the password for ***PIN*** and after this, try again for backup and it showing you for enter the **PIN** password and then, Backup process will be starting.

---

Edit :

after Set the `PIN`, use this Command :

> adb backup -all

this command will be show to you the windows like this :

[image]

Comment: Does it not show any verification window on the phone? Do I have to just wait and watch and hope that backup is going on?

Comment: Edit and updated.